# Make background "see-through" programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a little issue with the following. How do I get rid of the red background in the screenshot; in other words, I want to make the red background see-through (transparent) in the following screenshot:

***App running on Android:***

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the xml code that defines the portion of the screen that I am trying to change:

```
<com.flares.HashCircleMenuLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_menulayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="100dp">
            <!--android:background="@drawable/circle_bg3"-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@id/id_circle_menu_item_center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="104.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="104.0dip"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/turnplate_center_unlogin" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="116.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="116.0dip"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/turnplate_mask_unlogin_normal" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.flares.HashCircleMenuLayout>
```

Also, the HashCircleMenuLayout code:

public class HashCircleMenuLayout extends ViewGroup

```
{
    private int mRadius;
    private static final float RADIO_DEFAULT_CHILD_DIMENSION = 1 / 4f;
    private float RADIO_DEFAULT_CENTERITEM_DIMENSION = 1 / 3f;
    private static final float RADIO_PADDING_LAYOUT = 1 / 12f;
    private static final int FLINGABLE_VALUE = 300;
    private static final int NOCLICK_VALUE = 3;
    private int mFlingableValue = FLINGABLE_VALUE;
    private float mPadding;
    private double mStartAngle = 0;
    private String[] mItemTexts;
    private int[] mItemImgs;
    private int mMenuItemCount;
    private float mTmpAngle;
    private long mDownTime;
    private boolean isFling;
    private int mMenuItemLayoutId = R.layout.circle_menu_item;
    public HashCircleMenuLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int resWidth = 0;
        int resHeight = 0;
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                || heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            resWidth = getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
            resWidth = resWidth == 0 ? getDefaultWidth() : resWidth;
            resHeight = getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
            resHeight = resHeight == 0 ? getDefaultWidth() : resHeight;
        } else
        {
            resWidth = resHeight = Math.min(width, height);
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(resWidth, resHeight);
        mRadius = Math.max(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int childSize = (int) (mRadius * RADIO_DEFAULT_CHILD_DIMENSION);
        int childMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == GONE)
            {
                continue;
            }
            int makeMeasureSpec = -1;

            if (child.getId() == R.id.id_circle_menu_item_center)
            {
                makeMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (mRadius * RADIO_DEFAULT_CENTERITEM_DIMENSION),childMode);
            } else
            {
                makeMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childSize,childMode);
            }
            child.measure(makeMeasureSpec, makeMeasureSpec);
        }
        mPadding = RADIO_PADDING_LAYOUT * mRadius;
    }

    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener
    {
        void itemClick(View view, int pos);

        void itemCenterClick(View view);
    }

    private OnMenuItemClickListener mOnMenuItemClickListener;
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            OnMenuItemClickListener mOnMenuItemClickListener)
    {
        this.mOnMenuItemClickListener = mOnMenuItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        int layoutRadius = mRadius;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        int left, top;
        int cWidth = (int) (layoutRadius * RADIO_DEFAULT_CHILD_DIMENSION);
        float angleDelay = 360 / (getChildCount() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            if (child.getId() == R.id.id_circle_menu_item_center)
                continue;

            if (child.getVisibility() == GONE)
            {
                continue;
            }

            mStartAngle %= 360;
            float tmp = layoutRadius / 2f - cWidth / 2 - mPadding;
            left = layoutRadius / 2 + (int) Math.round(tmp* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mStartAngle)) - 1 / 2f* cWidth);
            top = layoutRadius  / 2 + (int) Math.round(tmp* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(mStartAngle)) - 1 / 2f* cWidth);

            child.layout(left, top, left + cWidth, top + cWidth);
            mStartAngle += angleDelay;
        }

        View cView = findViewById(R.id.id_circle_menu_item_center);
        if (cView != null)
        {
            cView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    if (mOnMenuItemClickListener != null)
                    {
                        mOnMenuItemClickListener.itemCenterClick(v);
                    }
                }
            });
            int cl = layoutRadius / 2 - cView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            int cr = cl + cView.getMeasuredWidth();
            cView.layout(cl, cl, cr, cr);
        }

    }

    private float mLastX;
    private float mLastY;
    private AutoFlingRunnable mFlingRunnable;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                mLastX = x;
                mLastY = y;
                mDownTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mTmpAngle = 0;
                if (isFling)
                {
                    removeCallbacks(mFlingRunnable);
                    isFling = false;
                    return true;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float start = getAngle(mLastX, mLastY);
                float end = getAngle(x, y);
                if (getQuadrant(x, y) == 1 || getQuadrant(x, y) == 4)
                {
                    mStartAngle += end - start;
                    mTmpAngle += end - start;
                } else
                {
                    mStartAngle += start - end;
                    mTmpAngle += start - end;
                }
                requestLayout();

                mLastX = x;
                mLastY = y;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float anglePerSecond = mTmpAngle * 1000
                        / (System.currentTimeMillis() - mDownTime);
                if (Math.abs(anglePerSecond) > mFlingableValue && !isFling)
                {
                    post(mFlingRunnable = new AutoFlingRunnable(anglePerSecond));

                    return true;
                }
                if (Math.abs(mTmpAngle) > NOCLICK_VALUE)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private float getAngle(float xTouch, float yTouch)
    {
        double x = xTouch - (mRadius / 2d);
        double y = yTouch - (mRadius / 2d);
        return (float) (Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }

    private int getQuadrant(float x, float y)
    {
        int tmpX = (int) (x - mRadius / 2);
        int tmpY = (int) (y - mRadius / 2);
        if (tmpX >= 0)
        {
            return tmpY >= 0 ? 4 : 1;
        } else
        {
            return tmpY >= 0 ? 3 : 2;
        }

    }

    public void setMenuItemIconsAndTexts(int[] resIds, String[] texts)
    {
        mItemImgs = resIds;
        mItemTexts = texts;

        if (resIds == null && texts == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("è�œå�•é¡¹æ–‡æœ¬å’Œå›¾ç‰‡è‡³å°‘è®¾ç½®å…¶ä¸€");
        }

        mMenuItemCount = resIds == null ? texts.length : resIds.length;

        if (resIds != null && texts != null)
        {
            mMenuItemCount = Math.min(resIds.length, texts.length);
        }

        addMenuItems();

    }

    public void setMenuItemLayoutId(int mMenuItemLayoutId)
    {
        this.mMenuItemLayoutId = mMenuItemLayoutId;
    }

    private void addMenuItems()
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        for (int i = 0; i < mMenuItemCount; i++)
        {
            final int j = i;
            View view = mInflater.inflate(mMenuItemLayoutId, this, false);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_circle_menu_item_image);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_circle_menu_item_text);

            if (iv != null)
            {
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setImageResource(mItemImgs[i]);
                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        if (mOnMenuItemClickListener != null)
                        {
                            mOnMenuItemClickListener.itemClick(v, j);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if (tv != null)
            {
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv.setText(mItemTexts[i]);
            }

            addView(view);
        }
    }

    public void setFlingableValue(int mFlingableValue)
    {
        this.mFlingableValue = mFlingableValue;
    }

    public void setPadding(float mPadding)
    {
        this.mPadding = mPadding;
    }

    private int getDefaultWidth()
    {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
        return Math.min(outMetrics.widthPixels, outMetrics.heightPixels);
    }

    private class AutoFlingRunnable implements Runnable
    {

        private float angelPerSecond;

        public AutoFlingRunnable(float velocity)
        {
            this.angelPerSecond = velocity;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            if ((int) Math.abs(angelPerSecond) < 20)
            {
                isFling = false;
                return;
            }
            isFling = true;
            mStartAngle += (angelPerSecond / 30);
            angelPerSecond /= 1.0666F;
            postDelayed(this, 30);
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

}
```

There must be a way of doing the above, either programmatically, or by changing the xml, but am not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I use a theme for all my activities with "android:theme" tag in android manifest file `

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true" >
    <activity></activity>`
```

I define red with 40 percent transparency color in the file "colors.xml".

The tag "color name=red_transparent">#**40**FF0000"

The number 40 is 40 percent transparency and FF0000 is color red.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3cb912</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="red_transparent">#40FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Then I edit the styles.xml to edit my theme to suit my needs, the tag,

"android:background" is defined with red_transparent color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!--  Customize your theme here.  -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/red_transparent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: How about only getting rid of the bottom red background on the menu?